# mysql JOIN ON IF()?

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I am trying to use sql such as this:

```
SELECT t.*, t2.* FROM templates t
LEFT JOIN IF(t.t_type = 0,'templates_email',
IF(t.t_type = 1,'templates_sms','templates_fax')) t2
ON t.t_id = t2.t_id;
```

Is it possible to do something like that?

basically I want to join on one of three tables based on the value from the row.

Is this recommended if it is possible?

---

**update**
So,

basically the `templates` table is the table that contains all the information that every template must have, eg name, id, description

then you have the `templates_x` tables these tables contain the fields that are unique to each template type.
(There are quite a few and having a single table with null fields for those not applicable is not practical).

The tables are called `templates_x` however the appropriate x is stored in the templates table as an int flag.

The join between the `templates_x` tables and the `templates` table is through the `t_id`.

So what do you suggest?

Comment: so you mean have a table which is basically

[id | tablename]
[0  | templates_email]
[1  | templates_sms]
[2  | templates_fax]

and then join to that table and join of the value of that?

Comment: Afaik, even that will not work, as the tablename for a join cannot be dynamic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL JOIN with IF conditions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771425/mysql-join-with-if-conditions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Is it possible to do something like that?

No, you can't use dynamically assigned tables (join or otherwise) without using dynamic SQL syntax (See [MySQL's PreparedStatement syntax](http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2005/11/mysql-5-prepared-statement-syntax-and.html)).

This non-dynamic re-write of your pseudo-query assumes that the three template tables you join to all have the same number of columns, and the same data types:

```
SELECT t.*, 
       te.*
  FROM TEMPLATES t
  JOIN TEMPLATES_EMAIL te ON te.t_id = t.t_id
 WHERE t.t_type = 0
UNION
SELECT t.*, 
       ts.*
  FROM TEMPLATES t
  JOIN TEMPLATES_SMS ts ON ts.t_id = t.t_id
 WHERE t.t_type = 1
UNION
SELECT t.*, 
       tf.*
  FROM TEMPLATES t
  JOIN TEMPLATES_FAX tf ON tf.t_id = t.t_id
 WHERE t.t_type NOT IN (0, 1)
```

Comment: and if they do not have the same column count?

Comment: @Hailwood: Assuming nothing similar beyond the `t_id` column, then you can't use UNION at all if you want data from the supporting tables.  Parred down to columns from the `TEMPLATE` table in the SELECT clause, you could use UNION...

Answer (score 4):

Instead of a conditional join, you can join the data then select which field you want.

Example:

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN t.type = 0 THEN [templates_email]
    WHEN t.type = 1 THEN [templates_sms]
    WHEN t.type = 2 THEN [templates_fax]
  END AS [selected_field]
FROM 
  t
LEFT JOIN t1 ON t.t_id = t1.t_id
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t.t_id = t2.t_id
LEFT JOIN t3 ON t.t_id = t3.t_id
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid it would have to be something like this (if all tables have the same columns):

```
SELECT t.*, t2.* FROM templates t
LEFT JOIN templates_email t2
ON t.t_id = t2.t_id
WHERE t.t_type = 0
UNION
SELECT t.*, t2.* FROM templates t
LEFT JOIN templates_sms t2
ON t.t_id = t2.t_id
WHERE t.t_type = 1
UNION
SELECT t.*, t2.* FROM templates t
LEFT JOIN templates_fax t2
ON t.t_id = t2.t_id
WHERE t.t_type NOT IN (0,1)
```

Or like this:

```
SELECT t.*, t1.*, t2.*, t3.*
FROM templates t    
LEFT JOIN templates_email t1
ON t.t_id = t1.t_id
AND t.type_id = 0
LEFT JOIN templates_sms t2
ON t.t_id = t2.t_id
AND t.type_id = 1
LEFT JOIN templates_fax t3
ON t.t_id = t3.t_id
AND t.type_id NOT IN (0,1)
```

.. and live with all your NULL columns.