# Using `as` column in `INNER JOIN` - `ON`

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use a calculated column, referred to by an alias, as a JOIN expression.

This is the query; the problem is with `idMem`.

```
SELECT IF(c.memGet=$idMemOnline,c.memSend,c.memGet) as idMem
FROM chat c
LEFT JOIN members m
ON (m.id = idMem)     // here the problem
WHERE (c.memSend=$idMemOnline || c.memGet=$idMemOnline) && c.isLast=true
```

Is there a way of using a calculated field as a JOIN key?

Comment: Possible a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771425/mysql-join-with-if-conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the alias in the `ON` clause. Use the `IF` function instead:

```
SELECT IF(c.memGet=$idMemOnline,c.memSend,c.memGet) as idMem
FROM chat c
LEFT JOIN members m
ON (m.id = IF(c.memGet=$idMemOnline,c.memSend,c.memGet)) 
WHERE (c.memSend=$idMemOnline || c.memGet=$idMemOnline) && c.isLast=true
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to get all last chat messages of a member, those where he is the sender and those where he is the recipient. You don't want to have an IF in the JOIN clause, even if MySQL can often optimize it.

```
SELECT IF (c.memGet=$idMemOnline, c.memSend, c.memGet) as idMem
FROM chat c LEFT JOIN members m
ON (m.id = c.memSend OR m.id = c.memGet)
WHERE (c.memSend=$idMemOnline OR c.memGet=$idMemOnline) AND c.isLast=true
```

But perhaps a better approach would be to select the two groups independently, which would yield a better use of indexes, for example if you had an index on `isLast` and `memSend`, and *another* index on `isLast` and `memGet`:

```
SELECT c.memSend as idMem
    FROM chat AS c WHERE (c.memGet=$idMemOnline AND c.isLast=true)
UNION
SELECT c.memGet as idMem
    FROM chat AS c WHERE (c.memSend=$idMemOnline AND c.isLast=true);
```

Or if you wanted information from members also,

```
SELECT m.name, idMem FROM (
    SELECT c.memSend as idMem
        FROM chat AS c WHERE (c.memGet=$idMemOnline AND c.isLast=true)
    UNION
    SELECT c.memGet as idMem
        FROM chat AS c WHERE (c.memSend=$idMemOnline AND c.isLast=true)
) AS c2 JOIN members AS m ON (id = $idMemOnline);

-- (or on (id = idMem) if you wanted data on the other member).
```

In the last case you would also want probably an index on `members.id` .

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69eb48/1) a working fiddle.